# Getting the only key of a Map from JsonSlurper

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have JSON that needs to be processed using Groovy. I am pretty sure that the JSON has only one key, with this format:

```
{ rootKey: [...] }
```

Where `rootKey` stands for different values (e.g. "customers", "stores", etc.).

Let's say I used JsonSlurper:

```
def map = jsonSlurper.parseText(myjson)
```

How do I obtain that rootKey string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `keySet` method to get the keys which is a list. Since, you mentioned only key, you can use the first element as shown below:

```
def jsonString = """{
  "rootKey": []
}"""
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
println json.keySet()[0]
```